# Deciphering the RSA encrypted message from three different public keys

Tags: encryption, rsa, cryptanalysis

I have three different 1024-bit public keys with common exponent $e$ but different moduli. A message $m$ is encrypted (without padding) using the three keys, which results in three different encrypted messages.

Given the three pairs of public keys $(N_i,e)$ and the encrypted messages $c_i=m^e\bmod N_i$ , how do I decipher the original message $m$ ?

Comment: Near duplicate of [_"Can you help me understand the RSA Broadcast Attack?"_](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/47063/555). Note: this attack works because RSA is misused. Without random encryption padding, enciphering a name on the class roll, even with a single public key, is totally unsafe; it is of paramount importance to understand why.

Comment: @fgrieu Yet, the linked duplicate does not a very good job of explaining [Håstad's broadcast attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith's_attack#H.C3.A5stad.27s_broadcast_attack). I'm feeling like either this question or the linked one could use an answer explaining things properly.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the question, the same message is directly encrypted to three different public keys using *textbook RSA*. This has dire consequences, including the following (with 1./2./3. not using the multiple public keys, and the answer likely thought at 5. or its extension 6.):

1. It severely limits the size of the message (to less than 128 octets).
2. A guess of the message can be checked by anyone with a public key $(N_i,e)$ and the ciphertext $c_i$, which by a standard assumption in cryptography includes adversaries. They simply encipher a guess of $m$ with $(N_i,e)$ and check it against $c_i$. Poof goes confidentiality if the message is a name on the class roll, a guessable password..
3. If $m$ is less than say $2^{70}$ , there is a good chance that there exits $r<2^{30}$ and $s<2^{40}$ with $m=r\cdot s$. In that case, regardless of $e$, there's a [meet-in-the-middle attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meet-in-the-middle_attack) recovering $m$: the attacker computes $c_0/r^e\bmod N_0$ for all candidates $r$ and store that for quick search (10 GiB of RAM for hash tables and 128 GiB of seldom used disk will do); then for each candidate $s$ computes $s^e\bmod N_0$ and searches that; it there's a match, $m$ is found as $r\cdot s$ .
4. If $e$ is small, and/or the message $m$ is small enough (less than about $2^{1023/e}$ ), then $m=\sqrt[e]{c_i}$ (where $i$ is the index of the largest $N_i$ and it is used straight, not modular arithmetic). Even though the $c_i$ are distinct, this attack could still work in the case at hand, when $m$ is close enough to the limit $\sqrt[e]{\max(N_i)}$ . Further, that *e<sup>th</sup> root attack* can be easily extended to like $m<2^{1060/e}$, and much more when we consider the multiple encryptions, see 6.
5. If $e=3$, the system is plain vulnerable to the archetypal *RSA broadcast attack* (also the simplest form of [*Håstad's broadcast attack*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith's_attack#H.C3.A5stad.27s_broadcast_attack)). $e=3$ is a common choice in textbook RSA, because that allows the fastest encryption, using modular squaring and one modular multiplication; and is as safe as can be when $m$ is essentially random in an interval like $[0,N_i)$ and chosen independently for each encryption (contrary to the situation at hand where the same $m$ was used thrice).

   We should first check that the three $\gcd(N_i,N_j)=1$ for $0\le i<j<3$. Otherwise, the GCD is a non-trivial factor of $N_i$ and $N_j$, and we have factored $N_i$ and $N_j$ (at least in two-factors RSA), and can compute a working private exponent and decipher, per the normal way in textbook RSA. Succeeding in that way is not supposed to happens, but does [here](https://smartfacts.cr.yp.to/index.html) and [there](http://web.stanford.edu/class/ee380/Abstracts/150513-slides.pdf#page=23), due to Random Number Generators that are not true, and gave the same results on different platforms, when they should not; and in academic exercises.

   Having thus checked (or blindly assumed) that we can invoke the [Chinese Remainder Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem), we use it to solve for $x$ the system of 3 equations $x\equiv c_i\pmod{N_i}$ for $0\le i<3$ with $x\in[0,\prod N_i)$. That goes:

   - $x\gets c_0$
   - $N\gets N_0$
   - For each $i$ with $1\le i<3$

     - $x\gets(((N^{-1}\bmod N_i)\cdot(c_i-x))\bmod N_i)\cdot N+x$
     - $N\gets N\cdot N_i$
   - At that point $N=\prod N_i$, and $x$ is the desired solution.

   Then we computes $m=\sqrt[3]x$ (which will be an exact integer); this is a non-modular cube root, and thus easy. This will always work because $m<\min(N_i)$, thus $m^3<N$, thus $m^3=x$ since by the CRT, there's no other $m$ with $m^3\equiv c_i\pmod{N_i}$.
6. Attacks 4. and 5. combine and can work for some $e>3$. If $m<\sqrt[e]{\prod N_i}$ , then after computing $x$ just as above it comes $m=\sqrt[e]x$ (which will be an exact integer).

   This can be extended to $m$ up to about $(3072+k)/e$-bit with with $O(2^k)$ work; with $e=5$ perhaps $m$ up to $\approx78$ bytes (out of the maximum capacity of $<128$ bytes). An idea is to scan integers $r$ with $0\le r<2^k$, until $\sqrt[e]{r\cdot N+x}$ is an exact integer.

   Further, we can save significant computational work in this search by reusing an approximation of $\sqrt[e]{r\cdot N+x}$ in order to test if $\sqrt[e]{(r+1)\cdot N+x}$ is an integer, and computing an approximation of $\sqrt[e]{(r+1)\cdot N+x}$.

   And perhaps that attack can get even better; see this [answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/8019/555) wondering about extending the *e<sup>th</sup> root attack* by combining Coppersmith's theorem with lattice methods.

---

Conclusions:

- Do not use textbook RSA without random encryption padding, unless enciphering a mostly random $m$ nearly as wide as the public modulus, and enciphering that $m$ only once.
- Rather, use a [sound random padding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding) for each RSA encryption, and [hybrid encryption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hybrid_cryptosystem) for the whole thing.
- Do not conclude that a large $e$ like $e=65537$ will always save the day; it does not. Apply the above!

Answer (score 12):

If $e = 3$ we can use [Hastad's Broadcast Attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coppersmith%27s_attack#H.C3.A5stad.27s_broadcast_attack) to recover $m$. We can write the three encrypted messages as follows:

$$c_1 \equiv m^3 \text{ mod } N_1$$
$$c_2 \equiv m^3 \text{ mod } N_2$$
$$c_3 \equiv m^3 \text{ mod } N_3$$

Using the [Chinese remainder theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_remainder_theorem) it is possible to find a value $c_4$ that has the following properties:

$$c_4 \equiv c_1 \text{ mod } N_1$$
$$c_4 \equiv c_2 \text{ mod } N_2$$
$$c_4 \equiv c_3 \text{ mod } N_3$$
$$c_4 \equiv m^3 \text{ mod }N_1N_2N_3$$

Note that in RSA any message we encrypt must be smaller than the modulus, so $m$ is smaller than $N_1, N_2, N_3$. This implies that $m^3 < N_1N_2N_3$, which in turn implies that $c_4 = m^3$. So to recover $m$ all we have to do is compute $m = \sqrt[3]{c_4}$ (for which there are known efficient algorithms).

In general, if we have $e = x$ then we need to have $x$ encryptions of $m$ under the same $e$ and different $N$ for this attack to work. This follows from the fact that we need to be able to find a value congruent to $m^e$ mod some value greater than $m^e$ so that we can take the $e$th root of that value to recover $m$. If we have $e$ moduli for which we know $c_i \equiv m^e \text{ mod } N_i$ then we can always construct such a value via the CRT since for $m < N_i$ it holds that $m^e < N_1N_2 ... N_e$.

Answer (score -1):

If $e$ is low, you can do next:
Solve system of three equations $x_1=c_1 \bmod n_1$, $x_2=c_2 \bmod n_2$, $x_3=c_3 \bmod n_3$ using Chinese Reminder Theorem. You should obtain result like $x=a \bmod n$.

Then calculate e-th degree root of $a$.

This works with low exponents, because it's hard to compute n-th degree root.

Comment: $x_i=c_i$ is the one and only solution to $x_i=c_i\bmod n_i$ (notice that $\bmod$ not immediately on the right of an opening parenthesis is the operator _remainder of Euclidean division_, akin to`%` in C, C++, Java, Go..). I guess it was meant $x\equiv c_i\pmod{N_i}$ and solutions $x\equiv a\pmod N$ with $N=\prod N_i$. OK..