# Example of breaking RSA with CRT

Tags: rsa, public-key

I understand that if the same message is sent to 3 people with $e=3$ that even with different public keys, the message can be decoded using the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

I have tried to figure out the steps to do so, but I am unable to actually lay it out even using small numbers. How would one decrypt a message $m$ = 10, for example with $n_1=6$, $n_2=35$, and $n_3=143$, with $e=3$?

Comment: Did you search this site. There are examples of this.

Comment: @kelalaka I have searched, it was more general and I could not replicate it myself. I think that the answer below is helpful in seeing the process though.

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/52504/555), except with small values. There's a [simple answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/52519/555), and [mine, with a step-by-step method (restrict to item 5)](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/52520/555).

Comment: Since you don't know the name: Håstad's broadcast attack.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have the three cipher texts $m^3\equiv c_1\equiv 4\pmod{6}$, $m^3\equiv c_2\equiv 20\pmod{35}$ and $m^3\equiv c_3\equiv 142\pmod{143}$. An application of the Chinese remainder theorem tells us that $m^3\equiv 1000\pmod{30030}$, but because $m$ is less than $\root 3\of{30030}$ we know $m^3=1000$. A regular cube root now recovers $m=10$.